# VisualForce Object-Field Issue

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

```
<apex:page standardController="litify_pm__Matter__c">

    <apex:form >

        <apex:pageBlock title="Accident Info">

            <!-- Use Apex to query the related Accident Info record -->

            <apex:variable var="accidentInfo" value="{!litify_pm__Matter__c.Accident_Info__r}" />

 

            <!-- Check if accidentInfo is not null -->

            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(accidentInfo))}">

                <!-- Add input fields for the Accident Info object's fields -->

                <apex:inputText value="{!accidentInfo.Address_Of_Premises__c}" />

                <apex:inputText value="{!accidentInfo.Anyone_Ticketed__c}" />

                <apex:inputText value="{!accidentInfo.Badge__c}" />

                <apex:inputText value="{!accidentInfo.CI_Vehicle_Year_Make_Model__c}" />

                <!-- Add more fields as needed -->

               

                <!-- Save button to update the changes -->

                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />

            </apex:outputPanel>

        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

I have an object called Matters and  I have another object called Accident Info under Matters object. I get errors such as "Could not resolve the entity from apex:inputField value binding '{!accidentInfo.Address_Of_Premises__c}'. apex:inputField can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.".

What might be the issue?

I tried to display my AccidentInfo but some of the fields are giving errors.